# Apache rewrite and urlencoding

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The apache rewrite module (apache 2.4) gives me headaches, I need your help.

I try to redirect my unlogged users to another url and pass the original url as a callback argument. 
When the url below is called :
`http://myapp.com/context?arg1=value1&arg2=value2`
then the user is redirected to :

```
http://myloginapp.com?callback=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%2Fcontext%3Farg1%3Dvalue1%26arg2%3Dvalue2
```

I have tried many flags ([NE], [B]) in my rewrite clause and tried some rewrite cond found in the forum without success...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all traffic to holding page unless logged in using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562941/redirect-all-traffic-to-holding-page-unless-logged-in-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

I think a found a part of the solution with :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)&(.*)
RewriteRule /(.*)$ https://myloginapp.com/?callback=http://myapp.com/$1\?%1_%2 [N]
```

With the N flag I can repeat the rewrite as long as & remains in the url. 
But it doesn't work when i try to replace the underscore in %1_%2 with %26.
And if I try to add the NE flag, apache can't compile the rule (N and NE flags are not allowed together ?).